# cannot filter the records where the column having hyphen in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, sql-like, postgresql-11

I have been using Like function to filter the records based on the user input, it works for all the characters but its not working for hyphen,below the condition where I'm using this Like function to filter the records having hyphen,

```
LIKE upper('%-%')
```

Comment: Must work. But UPPER is excess. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=961e9639d44f9d0089474a7ebe664cdd

Comment: i removed the UPPER still its not working

Comment: Show full query text - the problem is in somewhere else.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Maybe your values contain a different type of hyphen that might look identical but is actually a different character, i.e. different unicode code points.

Comment: There are different types of hyphens -- notably m-dash and n-dash.   You probably have an inconsistency between the pattern and the data.